# How use Content-Type=application/xml in oracle apex for pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, api, post, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to receive the data that I transmit in the body of the request in the xml format and transfer it to the select . Now I successfully manage to work with json, but I need it xml . 
my code :(

```
DECLARE 
    te sys_refcursor;
Begin

  htp.p('JSON ename = ' || :name);
  htt.p('JSON city  = ' || :city);

    open te for select * from mk_test where name = :name and city = :city; 
    apex_json.write('teas' , te);

end;
```

Comment: how get xml body request in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
OWA_UTIL.mime_header('application/xml');
```

it helped me .